# How to disable plugin suggestions in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

Would anyone how the path to disable plugin suggestions within Intellij? I have dismiss the suggestion every time I create a file for a new project and was hoping there is a way to disable them globally.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to `Settings` > `Appearance & Behavior` and select `No popup` from a dropdown menu in the `Plugins Suggestions` group on the list.

Answer (score 2):

`Settings` > `Appearance` & `Behavior` > `Notifications` >
`Plugins Suggestions` > `Popup type`

Modify it.